# Get href atribute and tag name for A element in HTML using DOMDocument

Tags: php, parsing, domdocument

I'm trying to get `href` attribute (url) and tag name from HTML using DOMDocument.
I have the following code, but I listing parameters together:

```
$searchNodeA = $dom->getElementsByTagName('li');
$searchNodeHref = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');

foreach($searchNodeA as $searchNode)
{
    $url = $searchNode->getAttribute('href');

    $acko = $searchNode->getElementsByTagName('a');
    $nazev = $acko->item(0)->nodeValue;

    echo "$nazev<br />";
}/**/

foreach($searchNodeHref as $searchNode)
{
    $url = $searchNode->getAttribute('href');
    echo "$url<br />";
}/**/
```

How do we suddenly announcing results?

$url - $nazev

Comment: Looks like you want to nest those `foreach`es?

Comment: Yes, but I will list a URL at the end of 1x $nazev

Comment: [Check these](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A741747+simple+html+parser), done using `simple html parser`, it uses an easy, `jQuery` like approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Xpath:

Select any `li` element

`//li`

Any `a` element inside a `li` element ...

`//li//a`

... with a `href` attribute

`//li//a[@href]`

Load, evaluate and iterate:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHtml('<ul><li><a href="#link">caption</a></li></ul>');
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//li//a[@href]') as $a) {
  var_dump(
    [
      'text' => $a->nodeValue,
      'href' => $a->getAttribute('href')
    ]
  );
}
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
  ["text"]=>
  string(7) "caption"
  ["href"]=>
  string(5) "#link"
}
```