# fetch same elements but different value from XML File using PHP

Tags: php, xml

I want to fetch image path from bbc news XML file but there are 2 same elements media:thumbnail so when i try to fetch the image , it fetch the first element image URL and its small one .... I want to fetch the 2nd element image URL

```
<media:thumbnail width="66" height="49" url="http://news.bbcimg.co.uk/media/images/79823000/jpg/_79823050_afpgetty_harry.jpg"/>  
<media:thumbnail width="144" height="81" url="http://news.bbcimg.co.uk/media/images/79823000/jpg/_79823051_afpgetty_harry.jpg"/>
```

One method i have tried;

```
 'img' => $node->getElementsByTagName('thumbnail')->item(0)->getAttribute('url'),
 'img1' => $node->getElementsByTagName('thumbnail')->item(0)->getAttribute('url')
```

i declared 2 different variables and tried to fetch the  URL as i thought i can use the 2nd URL but its not working thanks for helping

Comment: You just made a little typo. Your code actually works, but take care that if you want the second element, you need to use `item(1)` instead of `item(0)`. Additionally: [Use XPath](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24023272/367456).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$images =  $node->getElementsByTagName('thumbnail');
foreach ($images as $image)
{
    echo $image->getAttribute('url');   
}
```

Should do the trick

Comment: Thank you very much ... feeling dumb